# Mongodb database.collection confusion

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku

I created a MEAN project in heroku.
In MongoDB I have a DB / Collection like this:
`db == content / collection == android_main`
I have verified that the collection is in the proper database (and not in admin) via the following MongoSH exchange:

```
Atlas atlas-xxxxxx-shard-0 [primary] content> use admin
switched to db admin
Atlas atlas-xxxxxx-shard-0 [primary] admin> show collections

Atlas atlas-xxxxxx-shard-0 [primary] admin> use content
switched to db content
Atlas atlas-xxxxxx-shard-0 [primary] content> show collections
android_main
```

In MongoDB I also have a user w/ specific privs to read this db/collection.
[image]

In the code (Node.js) I use the following connection string:
`mongodb+srv://<USER>:<PASS>@<MONGO URL>/content?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
The connection completes successfully. I pass in the user I mentioned above, e.g. the user with just the specific read privs on the database (content) and collection (android_main).
In the code, the mechanism I use to get the `database` variable via the connection and connection string specifically is:

```
mongodb.MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, function (err, database) {
```

Now, in the code, in response to an `HTTP GET` I issue the following:

```
db.collection("android_main").find({}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
...
}
```

I get back this error:
`ERROR: user is not allowed to do action [find] on [admin.android_main]`

Question: how can I modify my code a/o setup to ensure the `db.collection.find()` call references the proper database? I would have thought this was taken care of in the connection, where the database is explicitly called out.

Comment: Have you tried `db.getSiblingDB("content").collection("android_main").find({}). ...`?

Comment: I put that call in and got the following `TypeError: db.getSiblingDB is not a function`

Comment: Can we also have the code portion where you set up `db`?

Comment: db setup via `MongoClient.connect()` has been added in above. Sorry for the ommission.

Comment: It's interesting to note that in the `MongoClient.connect()` method I printed out the attributes of the db that got passed in. Despite the fact that the connection string explicitly referenced db `content`, the db in question refers to `admin`. This is not at all straightforward nor explained well as far as I can tell, but it seems that Ray is on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to post the following answer which solves the issue above.
I found it by just playing around with random ideas.
I'd like to thank Heroku and their pathetic documentation for turning a 30 minute task into a 3 day ordeal.

```
client.connect(
    process.env.MONGODB_URI,
    function (err, database) {
        console.log("CONNECT...");
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            process.exit(1);
        }
        db = database.db(DATABASE);
        var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080,
            function () {
                var port = server.address().port;
                console.log("CONNECT App now running on port", port);
            }
        );
        console.log("CONNECT Done.");
    }
);
```

Apparently, to properly set the variable `db` (the one which you will use in the queries later) you should note that the `database` you receive in the connection callback is the admin database (that which was used for auth), and from that you make the `db()` request passing in the database you intend to use. All of this is utterly redundant b/c we pass the database we intend to use in the connection string. What a complete CF; but it's certainly not the 1st one. 
Enjoy.